# How could I use eclipse/java console window to invoke a event?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, event-handling

I know how to invoke a event by clicking the components on the GUI. But I want to do is to enter some command to the console window in eclipse and then some events can be invoked.
For example:
I enter `Click 1` in the console window
Then the `button 1` should be clicked and the corresponding event should be invoked.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do it?"*  A better question is, is there a ***reason*** to do it (with your IDE)?  Sounds like this actually needs a GUI testing framework.

Comment: The reason I want to do it is because I want to control my program in both way by using command and GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in straightforward way: after initialization of GUI, do not exit from main thread, but read in a loop from `System.in`, and then post an event with `SwingUtilities.invokelaterjava.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event)` as is advised in [Swing: How to create Events and dispatch them to a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808491/swing-how-to-create-events-and-dispatch-them-to-a-component)